# How to bind a ListBox itself

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I know how set bindings for i.e. the `ItemSource` or the `SelectedItem` of a `ListBox`. My Problem now is, that I have no clue how to bind the `ListBox` itself to a `ListBox` variable in my `ViewModel` to perform actions like `ListBox.ClearSelected()`.

Comment: you are breaking the MVVM here, you can not and should not have reference of UI Elements in VM layer

Comment: instead of `ListBox.ClearSelected()` reset (to null) selectedelement property in a *viewmodel*

Comment: _"I have no clue how to bind the ListBox itself to a ListBox variable in my ViewModel"_ -- why in the world would you want to do that? You could hack it: bindings work _strictly_ on properties, so if you managed to get the reference to the `ListBox` object into a property in the view, you could then set a binding to receive that property's value. But, it would be a horrible choice. Since you've bound to the `ItemsSource`, you (presumably) have a collection in your view model. If you want the `ListBox` emptied, just clear the collection. Don't mess with the `ListBox` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to clear `listbox` itself, try to set Selected item to `NULL`

Passing UI Elements to view model is only going to create many many many more issues.

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItemProp}"/>
```

VM

```
SelectedItemProp = null;
```

Comment: `{"SelectedItemProp"}` is invalid xaml syntax

Comment: yea possibly, not copied from ide, correct if you remember on top of your head :)